# How to test if a given path is a mount point

Tags: bash, unix, shell

Suppose do you want test if /mnt/disk is a mount point in a shell script. 
How do you do this?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I discover that on my Fedora 7 there is a mountpoint command.

From man mountpoint:

```
NAME
       mountpoint - see if a directory is a mountpoint

SYNOPSIS
       /bin/mountpoint [-q] [-d] /path/to/directory
       /bin/mountpoint -x /dev/device
```

Apparently it come with the sysvinit package, I don't know if this command is available on other systems.

```
[root@myhost~]# rpm -qf $(which mountpoint)
sysvinit-2.86-17
```

Comment: The solutions that parse output /etc/mtab can provide the wrong answer: root file system could be mounted read-only, and /etc/mtab may not have been updated since last boot. mount(8) often simply prints the content of /etc/mtab, and will give wrong answer for the same reason.

Comment: Thanks for this. Also note that the command exits with status 1 if the directory is not a mountpoint, which is quite useful.

Comment: Note that the `mountpoint` command currently just compares the device number of `stat(dir)` with `lstat(dir/..)` (similar to other answer), and it fails if the mount point was mounted using `mount --bind` to another part of the same filesystem.

Comment: It's there on ubuntu/debian.  This is probably the better solution, although the other ideas subscribe perfectly the unix way: that there is more than one.

Comment: @yonran `mountpoint` now reads `/proc/self/mountinfo`.

Answer (score 23):

Not relying on `mount`, `/etc/mtab`, `/proc/mounts`, etc.:

```
if [ `stat -c%d "$dir"` != `stat -c%d "$dir/.."` ]; then
    echo "$dir is mounted"
else
    echo "$dir is not mounted"
fi
```

When `$dir` is a mount point, it has a different device number than its parent directory.

The benefit over the alternatives listed so far is that you don't have to parse anything, and it does the right thing if `dir=/some//path/../with///extra/components`.

The downside is that it doesn't mark `/` as a mountpoint.  Well, that's easy enough to special-case, but still.

Comment: +1... FYI I had to use 'stat -c%d "/path"' instead of the options you described to compare device numbers.  It might just be a different in our systems; I'm on RHEL 5.5.  Also, for others see man stat(2) if you want to do this in a program.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work with mount --bind mount points. mounted or not mounted the _if_ is always false.

_Doesn't work even with stat -c%d_ - this is on RHEL as well.

Comment: @ephemient : Had to read it twice. Was unclear the first time. Reading stat man page helped to understand what you are doing.  I might have missed to notice this great answer. Thank you.

Comment: Your set of options compares the major device type, which will be the same in the example below. Instead, use Device Number. In the following code block, replace the semicolons with linefeeds to make it easier to read.
`mkdir -p /mnt/ramdisk/; mount -t tmpfs -o size=128M tmpfs /mnt/ramdisk; mkdir -p /mnt/ramdisk/ramdisk; mount -t tmpfs -o size=128M tmpfs /mnt/ramdisk/ramdisk; echo "Major Device type"; stat -c %t /mnt/ramdisk; stat -c %t /mnt/ramdisk/ramdisk; echo "Device Number"; stat -c %D /mnt/ramdisk; stat -c %D /mnt/ramdisk/ramdisk; umount /mnt/ramdisk/ramdisk; umount /mnt/ramdisk`

Comment: This test will return a false positive for a btrfs subvolume.

Answer (score 5):

Using GNU find

```
find <directory> -maxdepth 0 -printf "%D"
```

will give the device number of the directory.  If it differs between
the directory and its parent then you have a mount point.

Add /. onto the directory name if you want symlinks to different filesystems to
count as mountpoints (you'll always want it for the parent).

Disadvantages: uses GNU find so less portable

Advantages: Reports mount points not recorded in /etc/mtab.

Comment: This method will return a false positive for a btrfs subvolume.

Answer (score 3):

```
if mount | cut -d ' ' -f 3 | grep '^/mnt/disk$' > /dev/null ; then
   ...
fi
```

EDIT: Used Bombe's idea to use cut.

Comment: This will fail if the mount path contains spaces

Comment: You can replace the `mount` command with `cat /proc/mounts` which escapes spaces to avoid this problem.

Comment: @haggai_e: I hope you meant replace mount with a `< /proc/mounts`  redirect... avoid useless cat suffering!

Comment: Another completely worthless optimization: use 'grep -q' instead of '>/dev/null'

Comment: Thanks, I guess these are just bad habit that are hard for me to quit :)

Answer (score 3):

```
df $path_in_question | grep " $path_in_question$"
```

This will set `$?` upon completion.

Comment: This only works if `$path_in_question` is already in canonical form.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately both mountpoint and stat will have the side-effect of *MOUNTING* the directory you are testing if you are using automount. Or at least it does for me on Debian using auto cifs to a WD MyBookLive networked disk.
I ended up with a variant of the /proc/mounts made more complex because each *POTENTIAL* mount is already in /proc/mounts even if its not actually mounted!

```
cut -d ' ' -f 1 < /proc/mounts | grep -q '^//disk/Public$' && umount /tmp/cifs/disk/Public
```

```
Where
   'disk' is the name of the server (networked disk) in /etc/hosts.
   '//disk/Public' is the cifs share name
   '/tmp/cifs' is where my automounts go (I have /tmp as RAM disk and / is read-only)
   '/tmp/cifs/disk' is a normal directory created when the server (called 'disk') is live.
   '/tmp/cifs/disk/Public' is the mount point for my 'Public' share.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for mountedPath in `mount | cut -d ' ' -f 3`; do
    if [ "${mountedPath}" == "${wantedPath}" ]; then
        exit 0
    fi
done
exit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variant with "df -P" which is supposed to be portable:

```
mat@owiowi:/tmp$ f(){ df -P  | awk '{ if($6 == "'$1'")print   }' ; }
mat@owiowi:/tmp$ f /
/dev/mapper/lvm0-vol1  20642428  17141492   2452360      88% /
mat@owiowi:/tmp$ f /mnt
mat@owiowi:/tmp$ f /mnt/media
/dev/mapper/lvm0-media  41954040  34509868   7444172      83% /mnt/media
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mount | awk '$3 == "/pa/th" {print $1}'
```

Empty if is not a mountpoint ^^

Answer (score 0):

**stat --printf '%m'** shows the mount point of a given file or directory.

**realpath** converts relative paths to direct.

Comparing the results of the two will tell you if a directory is a mount point.  **stat** is very portable.  **realpath** is less so, but it is only needed if you want to check relative paths.

I'm not sure how portable **mountpoint** is.

```
if [ "$(stat --printf '%m' "${DIR}")" = "$(realpath "${DIR}")" ]; then
    echo "This directory is a mount point."
else
    echo "This is not a mount point."
fi
```

Without **realpath**:

```
if [  "${DIR}" = "$(stat --printf '%m' "${DIR}")" ]; then
    echo "This directory is a mount point."
else
    echo "This is not a mount point."
fi
```

Comment: I think `stat`'s `%m` also traverses the directory tree upwards comparing `st_dev`, as it is also vulnerable to the false positive of btrfs subvolumes.