# Check if directory mounted with bash

Tags: linux, bash, centos, mount

I am using

```
mount -o bind /some/directory/here /foo/bar
```

I want to check `/foo/bar` though with a bash script, and see if its been mounted? If not, then call the above mount command, else do something else. How can I do this?

CentOS is the operating system.

Comment: something like "if [[ $(mount -l ... | fgrep ... | wc -l) ]]; then ..."

Comment: Similar questions are on [Server Fault](//serverfault.com/q/50585), **Stack Overflow** and [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/38870).

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Running the `mount` command without arguments will tell you the current mounts.  From a shell script, you can check for the mount point with `grep` and an if-statement:

```
if mount | grep /mnt/md0 > /dev/null; then
    echo "yay"
else
    echo "nay"
fi
```

In my example, the if-statement is checking the exit code of `grep`, which indicates if there was a match.  Since I don't want the output to be displayed when there is a match, I'm redirecting it to `/dev/null`.

Comment: You don't need to check if it returns a string. `grep` returns a non-zero exit status if there are no matches. There is no need for the test, or the subshell created by $(). `if command | grep -q 'stuff'; then ...`

Comment: **This does not work with mount bind and therefore should not be accepted as the answer. This answer should be voted down.**


You cannot depend on `mount | grep ...` showing you that your mount bind is still active. If the underlying device is unmounted and remounted, the mount bind will actually no longer connect the two files/directories even though `mount` still shows it's connected.


And if you do `umount ...` it will even tell you it's not mounted, although `mount` said it was.

HUGE flaw in linux file system.

Comment: @DevNull: I'am having exactly the issue you've described. Any solution to this problem?

Comment: @Isaac, sorry for the delay in response.

I would try using `readlink -f`, which returns nothing when the path/file doesn't exist. If the underlying /mount/path/to_file isn't there (per readlink), the underlying mount is broke (remount the underlying mount and the binding).  If the underlying file is there and `readlink -f` says the binding-version of that file is not there, the binding is broken, just remount the binding.

Comment: @DevNull not work readlink -f also. readlink -f /path/not_mounted/ show path on proxmox NFS unmounted filesystem type NAS.

Comment: @abkrim, how about `stat -q "/path/to/mount/some_file"; echo $?` ?? it should be 0 if the file is there and 1 if not.

Comment: If there is a mount called `/mnt/md0xxx` so the command will indicate `/mnt/md0` as mounted while what it does not have to be...

Comment: I use this on VM's for easy check of mounted NFS shares:  
#!/bin/bash  
RED='\033[0;31m'  
GREEN='\033[0;32m'  
  
if [ -e /var/www/@Recycle ]  
  
then  
    echo -e "[  ${GREEN}OK \e[0m ]   NFS | WWW" >/dev/tty1  
NC='\033[0m' # No Color  
  
else  
    echo -e "[  ${RED}ERROR \e[0m ]   NFS | WWW" >/dev/tty1  
NC='\033[0m' # No Color  
fi

Comment: This answer is plainly wrong because it will falsely indicate that a directory is mounted if its name or device path is a substring of another path that is mounted.

Answer (score 206):

You didn't bother to mention an O/S.

Ubuntu Linux 11.10 (and probably most up-to-date flavors of Linux) have the `mountpoint` command.

Here's an example on one of my servers:

```
$ mountpoint /oracle
/oracle is a mountpoint
$ mountpoint /bin
/bin is not a mountpoint
```

Actually, in your case, you should be able to use the `-q` option, like this:

```
mountpoint -q /foo/bar || mount -o bind /some/directory/here /foo/bar
```

Comment: mountpoint /foo/bar says its not a mountpoint, but in fact it is. Very strange.

Comment: You actually have something mounted at the time you ran the 'mountpoint' command?  Even if it's intended to be a mountpoint, unless it *actually* has something mounted, it's just a directory.

Comment: +1, works on Ubuntu 10.10 as well. [It's been in Ubuntu since 8.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/i386/initscripts/filelist).

Comment: mountpoint is present in RHEL 6.3 too (probably even in earlier versions)

Comment: @Justin It seems that `mountpoint` will say that directory is not mountpoint if binded directory and the original directory are on the same device (see http://goo.gl/Hs7QKV).

Comment: Works perfectly on Suse Linux Enterprise Server 11 (SLES11SP2)

Comment: mountpoint is present and works on Debian 7 ("Wheezy") and UCS 4 perfectly, too

Comment: As mentioned in [another comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479226/how-to-test-if-a-given-path-is-a-mount-point#comment15969742_483472) mountpoint doesn't work with bind mounts. The snippet will mount the dir multiple times

Comment: Does mountpoint tell me whether this directory can be mounted (i.e. is in /etc/fstab) or whether it is currently mounted?

Comment: It only indicates whether there is *currently* something mounted.

Comment: would not work on a lot of embedded systems where mountpoint is missing

Answer (score 67):

The manual of `mountpoint` says that it:

> checks whether the given directory or file is mentioned in the /proc/self/mountinfo file.

The manual of `mount` says that:

> The listing mode is maintained for backward compatibility only. For
>   more robust and customizable output use findmnt(8), especially in your
>   scripts.

So **the correct command to use is `findmnt`**, which is itself part of the [`util-linux`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/) package and, according to the manual:

> is able to search in /etc/fstab, /etc/mtab or /proc/self/mountinfo

So it actually searches more things than `mountpoint`. It also provides the convenient option:

> -M, --mountpoint *path*
>
> Explicitly define the mountpoint file or directory. See also --target.

In summary, to check whether a directory is mounted with bash, you can use:

```
if [[ $(findmnt -M "$FOLDER") ]]; then
    echo "Mounted"
else
    echo "Not mounted"
fi
```

---

Example:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/foo/{a,b}
cd /tmp/foo

sudo mount -o bind a b
touch a/file
ls b/ # should show file
rm -f b/file
ls a/ # should show nothing

[[ $(findmnt -M b) ]] && echo "Mounted"
sudo umount b
[[ $(findmnt -M b) ]] || echo "Unmounted"
```

Answer (score 3):

I like the answers that use `/proc/mounts`, but I don't like doing a simple grep. That can give you false positives. What you **really** want to know is "do any of the rows have this exact string for field number 2". So, ask that question. (in this case I'm checking `/opt`)

```sh
awk -v status=1 '$2 == "/opt" {status=0} END {exit status}' /proc/mounts

# and you can use it in and if like so:

if awk -v status=1 '$2 == "/opt" {status=0} END {exit status}' /proc/mounts; then
  echo "yes"
else
  echo "no"
fi
```

Comment: This is lovely!  Precisely what you want for a small embedded system where no flashy tools like `mountpoint` or `findmnt` exist.  Very simple reply, much joy, such UNIX :)

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

```
is_mount() {
    path=$(readlink -f $1)
    grep -q "$path" /proc/mounts
}
```

Example:

```
is_mount /path/to/var/run/mydir/ || mount --bind /var/run/mydir/ /path/to/var/run/mydir/
```

For [Mark J. Bobak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9422683/1276501), `mountpoint` not work if mount with `bind` option in different filesystem.

For [Christopher Neylan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9422947/1276501), it's not need to redirect grep's output to /dev/null, just use `grep -q` instead.

**The most important, canonicalize the path by using `readlink -f $mypath`**:

- If you check path such as `/path/to/dir/` end with backslash, the path in `/proc/mounts` or `mount` output is `/path/to/dir`
- In most linux release, `/var/run/` is the symlink of `/run/`, so if you mount bind for `/var/run/mypath` and check if it mounted, it will display as `/run/mypath` in `/proc/mounts`.

Comment: I think "grep -q "$path " /proc/mounts" (with space) is even better... Otherwise is_mount ab will return true if abc is mounted?!

Answer (score 1):

The answers here are too complicated just check if the mount exists using:

`cat /proc/mounts | tail -n 1`

This only outputs the last mounted folder, if you want to see all of them just remove the tail command.

Answer (score 0):

Another clean solution is like that:

```
$ mount | grep /dev/sdb1 > /dev/null && echo mounted || echo unmounted
```

For sure, 'echo something' can be substituted by whatever you need to do for each case.

Comment: This is doing exactly the same thing as @ChristopherNeylan's answer.

Answer (score -5):

In my .bashrc, I made the following alias:

```
alias disk-list="sudo fdisk -l"
```

Comment: the request is about script and it is best to avoid sudo and program which target is to "manipulate disk partition"