# Bash script to Process two files and loop through to have mountpoint check

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have two files on is which contains host-names and another one which contains Linux mount-point information which i'm processing from file `mount.txt`.

What realy I'm looking for is to login to each hosts and check if the mount-point mentioned in the `/tmo/mounts` file exits on the hosts if it exits then just do `ls -ld mount-point` else skip it.

Somehow being a novice I'm not able to get how to process the mount-point check

```
#!/bin/bash
REMOTE_HOSTS="/tmp/hosts"
REMOTE_MOUNTS="/tmp/mounts"

awk -F":" '{print $1}' mount.txt | sort -u > $REMOTE_HOSTS
awk '{print $3}' mount.txt | sort -u > $REMOTE_MOUNTS

for hosts in $(cat $REMOTE_HOSTS);
do
    echo "------ $hosts ----"
    ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  -i /home/data/.ans root@$hosts 

done
```

Side-Note: `/home/data/.ans` is my rsa key for rot login.

### Hostname File:

/tmp/hosts

```
my-hosts01
my-hosts02
```

### Moun-point File :

/tmp/mounts

```
/data/oracle01
/data/oracle02
/data/oracle03
```

Please advise and help how could i do that, sorry if i could not make it more readable.

Comment: you can give the command(s) to ssh via stdin. possible `echo "hostname; ls -la  /data/oracle01; ls -la /data/oracle02" | ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /home/data/.ans root@$hosts` is helpfully

Comment: @gmu, thnx for the direction i can do that with ssh command itself if i have few mounts but i need them to be processed  from a file which is in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a difference between a mount-point, which is simply a directory, and a mounted element, which can be a storage or another thing.

Knowing that :

- if you want to check the mount-point existence, you simply have to check the directory : [Check if a directory exists in a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838/check-if-a-directory-exists-in-a-shell-script)
- if you want to check if an element is mounted on the mounted point : [Check if directory mounted with bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422461/check-if-directory-mounted-with-bash)

Comment: @-Jordan, thanks for the useful hints provided those are helpful, i'll try to understand these.