# How to check if /tmp and /proc filesysystems are mounted in a chrooted environment?

Tags: linux, bash, mount, chroot, procfs

I have already tried mounting the filesystems without checking like this:

```
sudo -- mount -t proc /proc $chroot_dir/proc
sudo -- mount --bind /tmp $chroot_dir/tmp
```

However, this would corrupt the parent OS session if already mounted, and I would have to restart the OS. I want to check if they're mounted beforehand.

Comment: `However, this would corrupt the parent OS session if already mounted` what? No it would not. What do you mean by "corrupt"? || https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208668/check-if-directory-is-a-mount-point https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479226/how-to-test-if-a-given-path-is-a-mount-point what research did you do?

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes, it did. Also, mountpoint would fail to recognize my chroot environment printing: `$chroot_dir is not a mountpoint`. Christian's solution actually is what worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in `/etc/mtab` what's currently mounted:

```
if grep $chroot_dir/proc /etc/mtab; then
  echo already mounted
fi;
```

And analogously for `tmp`.

Comment: I suggest to use `" $chroot_dir/proc "` with leading and trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the output of mount:

```
is_mounted() {
    local drives=`mount | grep "$1" | awk '{print $3}'`
    local arr=($drives)
    for d in $arr; do
        if [ "$d" == "$1" ]; then
            return 0
        fi
    done
    return 1
}
```

which returns 0 if the path $chroot_dir/proc is mounted. So after issuing:

```
sudo -- mount -t proc /proc $chroot_dir/proc
```

the above function will return 0:

```
is_mounted $chroot_dir/proc
echo $?
```

and 1 otherwise